# in react native when I load Welcome.js in App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

ERROR in ../src/screens/Welcome.js 6:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:4)
File was processed with these loaders:

- C:\Users\Riyaz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\source-map-loader\dist\cjs.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  | const Welcome = () => {
  |   return (

> ```
> <View>
> ```

|       Welcome
|

web compiled with 1 error

ERROR in ../src/screens/Welcome.js 6:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:4)
File was processed with these loaders:

- C:\Users\Riyaz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\source-map-loader\dist\cjs.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  | const Welcome = () => {
  |   return (

> ```
> <View>
> ```

|       Welcome
|

web compiled with 1 error

Comment: Could you post the code of the ```Welcome``` screen here?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for creating a functional component is

import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

export default function Welcome() {
return (

Welcome

)
}

and the syntax for creating class component is

import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Welcome extends Component {\n
render() {
return (

Welcome

)
}
}`

Comment: Your answer does not answer or help OPs question. While the question is missing crucial information, your answer is just a generic information about how to define components, which is not related to the problem in the question.